# What does it mean to 'pipe'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, poetry

On the first poem of his book *Songs of Innocence and Experience*, William Blake wrote:

> Piping down the valleys wild,
>
> piping songs of pleasant glee,
>
> on a cloud I saw a child,
>
> and he laughing said to me:

---

> 'Pipe a song about a Lamb!' (...)

According to the context and some googling, piping could be playing the flute, but I'm in doubt, cause it seems to be a voice-singed song.

Any help?

Comment: To pipe is to play music on a pipe (a musical instrument that resembles a tube with small holes in it).

Comment: On a side note, a person (usually, a kid) pipes something if they say something in a high-pitched voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* mean playing a flute (or, more likely, a countryman's hand-cut pipe). Note that in the third stanza the child asks the poet to "drop thy pipe" and sing the song he has been playing; in the fourth stanza the child asks the poet to write the song down, which he does in the final stanza (again with a "rural" instrument).

Note that this poem is not the one the poet performed for the child: this one affects to tell how the "Songs of Innocence" (including the one he performed, presumably "Little lamb, who made thee?") came to be written down.